# pop ups within xhtml without using javascript

Tags: jquery, xhtml, cdata

Keep getting errors using javascript within xhtml cdata tags.

is there an alternative way to generate a pop up link without using javascript coding such as jquery?

how would this be implemented....the site i am editing is all configured by xml files which is relativly like xhtml and uses  cdata tags.

Comment: You're correct that javascript in CDATA tags should be ignored.  I think the problem is that the site you're editing is configured by xml files, and it might do something with javascript tags for some reason.  More information would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it depends on what errors you are getting. Popups can be made in jQuery using the UI's .dialog.

**[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)**  is a link to the dialog documentation page.

Comment: using this code...
<htmlContent><en><![CDATA[       
    <p class="mainTitle">TITLE HERE</p>
    <p>CONTENT HERE</p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="popup"><img src="images/media/logo.jpg" alt="Google"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('popup').onclick= function() {
            return !window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=250,height=250');
        };
    </script>
]]></en></htmlContent>

i get this error....http://i55.tinypic.com/2r6ofia.jpg

using js within cdata tags are ignored if my understanding is correct.

Comment: is there any other way i can get a pop up to work...2 days i've been at it and no luck!!

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty popup in jquery. http://jsfiddle.net/justinrains/VvVsa/1/embedded/result/